# Keyboard Shortcut for Quitting Powershell

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, exit

If you can start powershell in admin privileges with keyboard shortcut WIN+X>A, how do you exit it. Alt+F4 does not work. I have tried other possible combinations but none seems to work.

Note: I am not asking about Powershell ISE(which i can close with Alt+f4). 
I am asking about the on-demand readily available terminal powershell.

Comment: If you want an existing Keystroke option you can type `Alt + Spacebar` and then the `Close` shortcut character.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns thanks, alt-space and then pressing c is quick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To close a PowerShell window using the system menu you can use

```
Alt + Spacebar, C
```

Nearly every Windows window has this option.  The `Close` or `Exit` option may differ based on the context so you'll just have try it and see.

This answer is accurate for the time of its writing but things may change.

Comment: Just tried and this still works for Powershell Core too. (Under windows)

Answer (score 3):

*Update*: If you're using **[Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)**, no workaround is needed: **<kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> works as-is**.
The following therefore only applies to regular (`conhost.exe`) console windows.

---

Note:

- For an *ad hoc* solution that uses *different keys* (strictly speaking, a keyboard shortcut followed by an additional, UI-language-dependent keypress), but requires *no setup*, see [No Refunds No Returns's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459052/45375).
- *This* answer provides a workaround that works transparently, i.e., with the *original* shortcut key, but it requires modification of your `$PROFILE` file; on the plus side, you can use the same technique to [make other unavailable shortcuts available too](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/280#issuecomment-136934572).

---

It is the imported-by-default [PSReadline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psreadline) module that prevents <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> from being effective<sup>[1]</sup>.

While unloading PSReadline (`Remove-Module -Force PSReadline`) is an option in principle, you'll lose valuable command-line editing features if you do.

The best approach is therefore to define a <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> handler *for PSReadline* that emulates the default behavior:

Add the following to your `$PROFILE`, which sets up a [PSReadline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psreadline) key-chord handler that uses the [`.SendKeys()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//8c6yea83(v=vs.85)) of the [`WScript.Shell` COM object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.85).aspx) to send <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> to the caller's console window, which closes it:

```bash
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler Alt+F4 -ScriptBlock { 
  (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('%{F4}')
}
```

---

<sup>[1] As of v2.0.0-beta3. The longstanding underlying technical problem is explained in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/280#issuecomment-136934572), which also contains workarounds for other standard keyboard shortcuts, such as <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Installing *Windows Terminal* causes **cmd** and **Powershell** to start *inside* Windows Terminal, offering you the option to close it with *CTRL + SHIFT + W*.

This does *not* apply to a command prompt opened as administrator. But you can start Windows Terminal as administrator. This may not apply for your problem, because you do not start the shell by yourself?

[image]